# What does this code from types.py do?

Tags: python

```
try:
    raise TypeError
except TypeError:
    try:
        tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
        TracebackType = type(tb)
        FrameType = type(tb.tb_frame)
    except AttributeError:
        # In the restricted environment, exc_info returns (None, None,
        # None) Then, tb.tb_frame gives an attribute error
        pass
    tb = None; del tb
```

I can't understand this code at all. What is it's purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a trick to get a traceback object and a frame object so that TracebackType and FrameType can be assigned their types.  It simply raises an exception so it can catch the exception, then get the traceback and frame from `sys.exc_info`.

Answer (score 0):

The code tries to find out the types used for the tracebacks returned by [`sys.exc_info()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) and assigned these types to the variables `TracebackType` and `FrameType`.

To do so it first needs to raise an exception and catch it (the `TypeError`), so that `sys.exc_info()` can return a traceback for this exception. Then this traceback gets inspected to determine the types. In the end the local `tb` variable is deleted to not keep unnecessary circular references around (see the warning in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) of `sys.exc_info()`).

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though this code is used to get the call stack.  If you research the [exc_info function](https://web.archive.org/web/20120101174152/http://pyref.infogami.com/sys.exc_info) from you'll find that the function returns a tuple of 3 values where the third is a Traceback object.  This object contains the call stack information which is then displayed.